# Identify item type when handling event in Exchange Web Services (EWS)

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using streaming notifications with the EWS API. On the event handler I pick up the fact that an item has been modified, but my attempt to bind the modified item to an email message fails. The error message is specifically

> The item type returned by the service (Appointment) isn't compatible
>   with the requested item type (EmailMessage).

It seems like there must be a way to identify the item type before attempting to bind it, but I'm not sure what that is. The error occurs on attempting to `Bind`, so I can't simply check for null. I could resort to `try/catch`, but would prefer to do this properly if there is a better way?

Summarised code:

```
void streamingConnection_OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (NotificationEvent notificationEvent in args.Events)
    {
        ItemEvent itemEvent = notificationEvent as ItemEvent;
        if (itemEvent != null) HandleItemEvent(itemEvent);
    }
}

private void HandleItemEvent(ItemEvent itemEvent)
{
    switch (itemEvent.EventType)
    {
        case EventType.Modified:
            EmailMessage modifiedMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(this.ExchangeService, itemEvent.ItemId);
            // error occurs on Bind if the item type is not an EmailMessage (eg, an Appointment)
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the correct way to bind is to use the generic `Item.Bind` method, then check if the item is an `EmailMessage` type. To do this robustly (handle potential issues where the item is moved before it can be bound) I put the logic into a method, similar to below:

```
private EmailMessage BindToEmailMessage(ItemId itemId)
{
    try
    {
        Item item = Item.Bind(this.ExchangeService, itemId);
        if (item is EmailMessage) return item as EmailMessage;
        else return null;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then change the logic in my existing method to

```
EmailMessage modifiedMessage = BindToEmailMessage(itemEvent.ItemId);
if (modifiedMessage != null) ...
```